# Using rack middlewares directly from Rails actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I have a Rack middleware that I want to embed in my Rails app. By embed, I mean injecting it into my application's layout, so that `<%= yield %>` contains the body of what the Rack app returns.

Here's my current solution:

```
def show
  result = MyRackApp.new.call(request.env)
  render :text => result[2].read, :status => result[0]
end
```

This is problematic, though, since `result[2]` does not always have a IO style `read` method, it might be a `Rack::File` for example.

So, how do I make a Rails controller render a `[200, {}, some_io_object]` type Rack response? Alternatively, can I do it the other way around with a Rack middleware that is able to render Rails layouts?

I'm using Rails 3.0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a rack application from Rails, you have to mount it from your router (routes.rb)

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do 
  # Other routes

  mount MyRackApp => "/pathToReachIt"

  # root to: '...'
end
```

More info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-mount)